# Sessions lost after upload image

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-3, session

Hi in my mvc3 application i have the following issue:
My users can upload an image after they are logged in with forms authentication. Now there are customer complaining they can't upload a file. I investigated this issue and see that when they upload an image, all sessions are lost. They are not logged in anymore so there is an object is null reference error when i try to get the login to put the image in the database. I see the image is uploaded correctly but they are logged out and i think all sessions are lost. perhaps this is because the application pool has been recycled or the working process? They can't upload images larger than 500kb so why should the application pool recycle? Can anyone suggest me what to do? thanks in advance.

EDIT added some code :

View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Fotos", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <label>Afbeelding:</label><br />
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" title="Kies uw afbeelding" />
         <br />
        <label>Titel:</label><span style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;"> @MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewBag.titel)</span><br />
        <input type="text" name="Title" value="" />
        <br /><label>Omschrijving:</label><span style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;"> @MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewBag.omschrijving)</span><br />
        <textarea name="Beschrijving" rows="4" cols="25"></textarea><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Foto uploaden" />
    }
```

this is the controller code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string Title, string Beschrijving)
    {
        try
        {
            MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */);
            string uploader = currentUser.UserName;
            string uploadermail = currentUser.Email;

                using (var ctx = new DB_24468_weerstatEntities())
                {
                    var imagetype = file.ContentType;
                    if (imagetype.Contains("image"))
                    {
                        if (file.ContentLength > 0 && file.ContentLength < 500000)
                        {
                            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Weerfotos"), fileName);
                                file.SaveAs(path);
                                var link = "/Content/Images/Weerfotos/" + fileName;
                                var image = new Image();
                                image.Name = fileName;
                                image.Url = "../.." + link;
                                image.Approved = false;
                                image.Username = uploader;
                                image.Description = Beschrijving;
                                image.Title = Title;
                                ctx.AddToImages(image);
                                ctx.SaveChanges();

                        }
                    }

                }

            return View();          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            throw;
        }
```

The code fails directly when trying to get the current username or email because the session is lost.. If i don't get any session details, everything works fine, but the user is logged out after posting his image..

Comment: Where is your code and how are trying to use sessions?If you show us some code how are you using it then we can try to fix it!And which upload control are you using?

Comment: i edited my post with extra code..

Comment: Are you using any flash uploader?